# creating dynamic string based on values submitted using php

Tags: php

I have around 8 fields in my page for eg:,filed1,filed2,field3, etc..

If a user enters field1 and filed 2 .I am trying to create a string as filed1=2&filed2=3

if a user enters only field2 and field3 then field2=test&field3=testing

Basically Not appending empty fileds.How it possible in php ?

I tried like this but not the correct way

```
if($_POST['filed1']!='')
$append = $_POST['filed1'];
if($_POST['filed1']!='' && $_POST['filed2']!='')
$append = 'field1='.$_POST['filed1'].'&field2='.$_POST['filed2'];
```

Comment: did you coded something yet ? if yes post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = '';

if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
    $fields = array_filter($_POST); // filter array from empty values
    $string = http_build_query($fields); // build url query string same as your case
}
```

For manuals:

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

[http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

**Update:**

```
$string = '';

if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
    $wanted = array(
        'clientUrlpass' => '', 
        'clients'       => '', 
        'location'      => '', 
        'cmpt'          => '', 
        'datefirst'     => '', 
        'da‌​tesecond'    => ''
    );

    foreach($wanted as $key => &$value)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$key]))
        {
            $value = trim($_POST[$key]);
        }

        if (!$value)
        {
            unset($wanted[$key]);
        }
    }   
        //this not needed while we already excluded empty values
        //$fields = array_filter($_POST);

    $string = http_build_query($wanted);
}
```

Comment: how to pass my own string like filed1,filed2 etc to the string

Comment: you have `$_POST` array, if you don't want to use it, pass your own array to `array_filter`, or you can add your own key/value pairs to  $fields

Comment: But again, even in your edited example you show that `filed1,filed2` comes from post by user, so it's already included in my answer

Comment: I am getting everything fromm the form like this _search=false&nd=1414130004257&rows=-1&page=1&sord=asc&clientUrlpass=bc&clients=api&location=9921&cmpt=true&datefirst=08%2F24%2F2014&datesecond=10%2F24%2F2014.I need only follwoing url string clientUrlpass=bc&clients=api&location=9921&cmpt=true&datefirst=08%2F24%2F2014&datesecond=10%2F24%2F2014 . How to remove unwanted parts

Comment: I solved it another way.Please check my answer below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63574/discussion-between-aniltc-and-george-garchagudashvili).

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayPost = array('clientId'=>$clients,
                            'locationIds'=> $location,
                            'personIds' =>$person,
                            'status'=>$status,
                            'competitor' =>$cmpt,
                            'startDate'=>$firstDate,
                            'endDate'=>$secondDate,
                            'sourceIds' => $source
                    );

            $fields = array_filter($arrayPost); // filter array from empty values
            $filterOutKeys = array('_search','nd','rows','page','sord');
            $filteredArr = array_diff_key( $fields, array_flip( $filterOutKeys ) );
            $stringToPass = http_build_query($filteredArr); // build url query string same as your case
        }
```